# Fancybox 2 - handle 'beforeLoad' event when images are being preloaded

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using Fancybox 2 to load a gallery of images. I'm using the `beforeLoad` event callback to alter the image url on-the-fly based on the user's viewport size. This works perfectly so long as the images are not preloaded (which they are by default).

I've noticed that when you click the original image which fires the Fancybox, it fires the `beforeLoad` event once, and then proceeds to pre-load a further 3 images in the gallery. These **preloaded images do not fire the `beforeLoad` event**. But when you click "next", the `beforeLoad` event **does** fire. Since I am changing the url of the image, this means the preloaded image is different to the one it actually displays. This is a waste of bandwidth and makes the page feel much less responsive.

I could, in theory, change every single source image on the page on page load and whenever the viewport is resized, but I don't like this approach. Is there a way to get `beforeLoad` to fire when the images are preloaded? Or a way to capture the `preload` event?

Comment: any callback will only run with the current element so don't expect it to be fired with any preloaded images. On the other hand, if you are changing the URL on the fly, there is not way to preload the dynamic URLs unless you build the gallery inside the script on the fly too. I guess your option is disable preloading to avoid the wast of bandwidth

Comment: @JFK I thought this may be the case. I have already disabled preloading, as you say, to avoid the wasted bandwidth. I suppose it's something I can live with. It would be cool to have a `beforePreload` callback, but I think that's wishful thinking. Thanks.

Comment: you can always suggest that to the developer here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues